# WebBrowser textbox value not being set c# Console Application

Tags: c#, automation, console-application

I am currently using a WebBrowser function in a c# application to automate a login and get information. The problem is when I set a textbox's value by ID, it does not work, it remains as it was (I checked by getting the console to write its value). Here is my code

```
br.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("Value", username);
br.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("Value", password);

br.Document.GetElementById("LoginBtn").InvokeMember("click");

//authcode
Thread.Sleep(5000);

Console.WriteLine(br.Document.GetElementById("username").InnerText) // This does not retrieve the data.
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `Value` attribute, then checking the `InnerText` of the tag. Assuming "username" is an input field, it won't have any inner text. You need to check the value of the `Value` attribute.

```
Console.WriteLine(br.Document.GetElementById("username").GetAttribute("Value");
```